# Get data starting from the middle of the table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a question. I want to get data from the middle of the table. But the problem is I can't start from the middle. I have read that rownum can't be used for this. But i dont know how to do this with another method. Anyone have any clue how to do this? Thank you.

Below is an example.

select count(1) --9857
from time_day_dm
where rownum between 5000 and 9857

The output would be 0.

What i expect would be 4857.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to retrieve half of records from a table - Oracle 11g](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30781979/how-to-retrieve-half-of-records-from-a-table-oracle-11g)

Comment: Table has no "begin" or "end" and `select` statement without `order by` returns result set in arbitrary order. Please clarify what do you mean as "middle"

Answer (score 2):

`rownum` won't help here (as you already know).

What you might do, is to use a couple of analytic functions (`count`, to find number of rows in the table; `row_number`, to *sort* them).

Here's an example based on Scott's `emp` table. This is its contents:

```
SQL> select empno, ename, job, sal
  2  from emp
  3  order by ename;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              SAL
---------- ---------- --------- ----------
      7876 ADAMS      CLERK           1100
      7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        1600
      7698 BLAKE      MANAGER         2850
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER         2450
      7902 FORD       ANALYST         3000
      7900 JAMES      CLERK            950
      7566 JONES      MANAGER         2975
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT       5000
      7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN        1250
      7934 MILLER     CLERK           1300
      7788 SCOTT      ANALYST         3000
      7369 SMITH      CLERK            800
      7844 TURNER     SALESMAN        1500
      7521 WARD       SALESMAN        1250

14 rows selected.
```

Query you might be interested in looks like this:

```
SQL> with temp as
  2    (select empno, ename, job, sal,
  3       row_number() over (order by ename) rn,
  4       count(*) over () cnt
  5     from emp
  6    )
  7  select *
  8  from temp
  9  where rn between cnt/2 and cnt;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              SAL         RN        CNT
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7566 JONES      MANAGER         2975          7         14
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT       5000          8         14
      7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN        1250          9         14
      7934 MILLER     CLERK           1300         10         14
      7788 SCOTT      ANALYST         3000         11         14
      7369 SMITH      CLERK            800         12         14
      7844 TURNER     SALESMAN        1500         13         14
      7521 WARD       SALESMAN        1250         14         14

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: ahh, this solution can work. thank you mr littlefoot!